# Can I use res.redirect and res.send simultaneously in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to print user's info on the landing page after they get logged in. I am using `res.redirect` to redirect to landing page i.e index1.html after a user get successfully logged in.

Now I want to get user info. Here is my node.js code:

```
app.post('/login-feedback', function (req, res) {

    dbConn.then(function(db) {
        delete req.body._id; // for safety reasons
        var dd = db.db("customermanagement");

        dd.collection('admin').findOne({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else if(user){
       req.session.user = user;
       console.log( req.session.user.username);
          res.status(200);
          res.redirect('/index1.html');
        }
        else {

         res.redirect('/login1.html');

        }
    });
  });
});
```

I would love if you will tell me explicitly everything step by step.

Comment: You cannot sent res.redirect and res.send simultaneously in nodejs. You will get error like *"headers cannot be set after they are sent."*

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan i know that sir. is there any way to solve this problem like i want to print users info on index1.html

Comment: Why not use `res.render()` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data to a static file, like an `html` file, you should use `res.render` :

```
res.render('/login1.html', {user: req.session.user.username})
```